# Reverse related object lookup ( _set )is not accessing objects

Tags: python, html, django, django-models, django-views

I am Building a BlogApp and I stuck on a Problem. I am trying to access two model objects but Failed many times.

models.py

```
class Topic(models.Model):
    topic_no = models.CharField(max_length=100,default='')  
    topic_title = models.CharField(max_length=200,default='')
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Profile,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.dairy_title

class Entry(models.Model):
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, on_delete=models.CASCADE,default='',related_name='topic')
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,null=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    note = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.topic)
```

views.py

```
def show_entry(request):
    showd = Entry.objects.all()

    context = {'showd':showd}
    return render(request ,'mains/showd.html', context)
```

showd.html

```
{% for post in topic.journel_set.all %}


{{ post.topic_title }}

{{ post.note }}


{% endfor %}
```

**The Problem**

I am trying to access both model's Objects in showd.html.

**What have i tried**

I saw tons of Answers like :- [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099037/reverse-foreignkey-lookup)   [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14348909/reverse-fk-lookup-with-related-name) and Many More answers about reverse related object lookup. BUT nothing is worked for me.

I don't know am i doing wrong in this.

Any help would be Appreciated.

Thank You in Advance.

Comment: First of all you are not passing  topic into context  only showd, moreover you did not post Journal model at all

Comment: Do i need to pass topic into context for access the objects of different Model which is ForeignKey with it ?

Comment: topic.journel_set.all does not make sense as there is no topic set in context. showd.topic.journel_set.all would make some sense but you did not post Journel object. Instead explain what exactly you want to achieve and do https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I posted Journel object by mistake .

Comment: I passed `topic` in context and put `{% for post in showd.topic.journel_set.all %}` BUT it didn't work.

Comment: woooowwww..............

Answer (score -1):

`Entry` has `ForeignKey` towards `Topic` it is **not reverse accessor** so `Entry` has only one `Topic`

So you could for instance do

```
{% for entry in showd %}


    {{ entry.topic.topic_title }}
    
    {{ entry.note }}

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: i did pass `context = {'topic':topic'}`

Comment: AND what do you mean by `Towards Topic` ?

Comment: what exactly didn't work. for the code sample above this would list entry and related topic, and you did not pass it in context in a way you are mentioning in a comment as in your question source is line   context = {'showd':showd}. 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/

Comment: what if i make a single model for it ? I mean, I can do it all in a single model

Comment: I just did ask you a question about Code. No matter where or when.

Comment: It is relevant, this is not forum. there are certain rules. Questions are not meant to be asked in comments

Comment: Question is Question, no matter where is asked.

Comment: Ill give you some links to consider and leave discussion with correct answer to your question as it currently stands. Misplaced question will unlikely be answered.
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions | https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266767/what-is-the-the-best-way-to-ask-follow-up-questions | https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188625/etiquette-for-russian-doll-questions

Comment: I also DoNotCare about Reputation.